# Make X the subject of the equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Make $x$ the subject of the equation:

> $4^{ax} = b * 8^x$

I have tried to substitute the powers of 2 into the equation and have so far got

> $2^{2ax} = b * 2^{3x}$

however I am now stuck. If you can, can you please show me ways to get $x$ on its own?
Also I have just started A levels and know nothing about logarithms

Comment: An usual criterion on Math stackexchange is that you need to show at least some work/ask about a particular thing you're stuck with. Otherwise this is likely to get closed as lacking context. Having said that, have you tried to substitute $4=2^2$ and $8=2^3$?

Comment: What is a subject

Comment: "*I have just started A levels and know nothing about logarithms*"  Logarithms go hand in hand with exponentials.  If you know how exponentials work, then you are more than halfway done with understanding logarithms and vice versa.  Saying that $x = y^z$ is equivalent to saying that $\log_y x = z$.  All of the properties of exponentials that you know translate into properties about logs and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Noting that $4^{ax}=2^{2ax}$ and $8^x=2^{3x}$, using the laws of logs $\ln(ab)=\ln a+\ln b$ and $\ln(a^b) = b\ln a$, we get

\begin{align*}
    &4^{ax} = b \times 8^x\\
   \implies &2^{2ax}=2^{3x}\,b\\
   \implies &\ln(2^{2ax})=\ln(2^{3x}\,b)\\
   \implies & 2ax\ln2=3x\ln2+\ln b\\
   \implies &x\ln 2(2a-3)=\ln b\\
   \therefore~~&\boxed{\,x=\frac{\ln b}{(2a-3)\ln2}}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$\log(a\cdot b^x) = \log(a)+x\log(b)$

> So, supposing $4^{ax}=b\cdot 8^x$, by applying $\log_2$ to each side we have $\log_2(4^{ax})=\log_2(b\cdot 8^x)$ which simplifies to...

Answer (score 0):

Observing that $4=2^2$ and $8=2^3$ gives $$(2^2)^{ax}=(2^3)^x\cdot b,$$ or equivalently $$2^{2ax}=2^{3x}\cdot b.$$ Now, taking logarithms on both sides gives $$2ax\log(2)=3x\log(2)+\log(b),$$ then $$2ax\log(2)-3x\log(2)=\log(b).$$ factorising $x\log(2)$ out $$x\log(2)(2a-3)=\log(b).$$ Thus $$x=\frac{\log(b)}{\log(2)(2a-3)}.$$

Answer (score 0):

So ... $$2^{2ax-3x}=b$$ i.e. $$(2a-3)x=\log_2 b$$ i.e. $$x=\frac{\log_2 b}{2a-3}$$ I don't believe there is any way you can avoid using logarithms.

Comment: The problem here is that I was never taught logarithms having recently going from GCSE to A levels...

Comment: @TheBeast It looks like the time has come to cross that bridge...